# как безболезнено обновить boost c 1.40 до 1.58

Tags: c++, boost

Столкнулся с проблемой. Потребовалось использование на проекте ***boost.log***.
Штука, вроде, хорошая, с документацией тоже всё хорошо. У меня проект (большой, с кучей модулей и т.д.) использует ***boost_1.40***, лога в нём ещё нет.

Решил попытаться обновиться, всё равно рано или поздно это придётся сделать, да и поддерживать библиотеки в актуальном состоянии полезно. 
Но вот тут меня прям разочаровало. Сначала посыпались предупреждения вида

> Boost.Signals is no longer being maintained and is now deprecated...

потом выяснилось что в `boost::path` тоже полно всего поменялось (выкинуты методы `directory_string` и `file_string`, например). Править и разбираться с каждым таким несоответствием - у меня и жизни не хватит.

Посоветуйте, может я что-то делаю не так? Неужели у буста нет совместимости с кодом, написанным под старые версии?

Или, может быть, мне стоит как-то придумать способ привинтить log отдельно, не смотря на то, что весь буст всё равно используется и ставится при сборке. Работа в Debian.

Comment: Все же между 1.40 и 1.58 - 5.5 лет разницы, за это время там ес-сно наменяли/наломали много всего, ради этого буст вобщем-то и затевался в противовес инертности с++/стл. Имх не стоит ожидать от этой сборной солянки либ такой поддержки.

Comment: @Abyx , так то оно так, только работать это чудо уже не будет(
# if defined(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATED)
    //  deprecated functions with enough signature or semantic changes that they are
    //  not supplied by default 
    const std::string file_string() const               { return string(); }
...
}`